# Como funciona a função current?

Tags: php, array, referência

Faz algum tempo que costumo sempre utilizar a função `current()` no PHP, para obter o primeiro elemento do *array* (o que na verdade não é sua funcionalidade, pois ela retorna o ponteiro atual em que o *array* está) e venho notando uma coisa que me deixou um pouco confuso comparando com as funcionalidades de `next()`, `prev()` e `reset()`.

E explico o por quê.

No [manual do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.current.php) e até mesmo no *Notepad++*, vemos que o argumento de `current()` é uma passagem por referência de um elemento do tipo `array`, da mesma maneira que `next()` e `prev()`.
Inclusive, a declaração da função é essa:

```
mixed current ( array &$array )
```

Porém, se você utilizá-lo em um *array* retornado de função ou mesmo de um *array* temporário (no caso, declarado diretamente como argumento de `current()`) ele funciona normalmente (sendo que o argumento seria uma variável passada por referência).

```
current([1, 2, 3]);// 1
current(explode(',', '1, 2, 3')); //1
$array = [1, 2, 3];
current($array); //1
```

Agora, o que deixa a minha confusão ainda maior é que, se eu passo um *array* diretamente em funções como `next()` e `prev()`, isso gera um erro fatal:

```
next([1, 2, 3]);
//Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference
echo next(explode(',', '1, 2, 3')); 
//Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference
```

A questão é: Se o manual do PHP especifica na declaração da função que `current()` trabalha com `arrays` passados por referência (como muitas outras funções usadas para `arrays`), por que ela é a única que funciona com *arrays* passados diretamente como argumento (como no primeiro exemplo)?

**Nota**: O Manual do PHP é bem enfático: `mixed current ( array &$array )`

Comment: Acabo de descobrir algo importante: Usando o [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), verifiquei que a função current começou a se comportar assim a partir da versão 5.1 do PHP.
Anteriormente a essa versão supracitada, quando se passava um parâmetro que não fosse uma variável em `current()` (por causa da passagem por referência), isso gerava um erro fatal.
Podemos deduzir que, no manual, `mixed current ( array &$array )` é uma referência à maneira que essa função se comportava antigamente.

Comment: O php nem o manual não está reportando o uso de `current()` corretamente.
O código `current(1)` gera **current() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given**, porém se você fizer `current(new stdClass)`, ele não gera aviso nenhum.
Se expera array, por que aceita objeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de muito tempo e de, até mesmo, esquecer dessa pergunta, encontrei a [resposta do pessoal do PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68995).

Se eu não entendi muito bem a resposta, auxiliem editando-a.

Segundo um tal de `aharvey@php.net`:

> Non-iterator objects are iterable like arrays, mostly for BC reasons.
>   This is expected behaviour, but I don't think we should change the
>   manual page to note that — effectively, it'll be treated like an array
>   regardless, and it's confusing.

Que traduzindo é (google tradutor):

> Objetos não-iteradores são iteráveis como matrizes, principalmente
>   por razões de compatibilidade reversa. Esse comportamento é esperado, mas eu não acho que nós
>   deveríamos mudar a página do manual. Note que ele
>   vai ser tratado como uma matriz de qualquer maneira, e isso é confuso.

Comment: Tradutores, fiquem à vontade!

Comment: Confusa é a resposta que ele te deu :D

Comment: A resposta é tão confusa quando a função :D

Comment: Depois de ler 10 vezes, acho que entendi. Está claro pra você o que ele quis dizer?

Comment: Explica o que acontece com `current` (correto), mas não explica a questão do operador de referência estar lá no manual. Ou seja, a explicação dele deixa claro que o manual está errado

Answer (score 12):

Porque não há necessidade de passá-lo por referência, a única coisa que esta função faz, é retornar o conteúdo do ponteiro atual do array, e isto não vai modificar o array, não sendo necessário passá-lo por referência.

Outros exemplos de `current()` e outras funções do mesmo segmento:

```
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'plane';

$arr = array();
var_dump(current($arr)); // bool(false)

$arr = array(array());
var_dump(current($arr)); // array(0) { }
```

Note que todas funções simplesmente retornam e modificam o ponteiro.

Quanto ao erro que gerou ao tentar aplicar `next()` na declaração do array, é porque estas funções foram feitas para trabalhar com o ponteiro do array.

Mas se você tentar declarar o array dentro da função, o ponteiro não existe, e por isso gera o erro que você postou na pergunta.

**Ponteiro** está diretamente ligado a criação da variável do tipo array, é o índice da variável, que só existe a partir do momento que você a declara.

O manual informa que o array é passado por referência:

```
mixed current ( array &$array )
```

Isto acontece porque quando usamos funções deste "grupo", como `next()`, ela altera a posição do ponteiro, ou seja, não é necessário passar por referência, pois a própria função faz isto, alterando a posição do ponteiro ex.:

```
$var = array(1,2,3);
echo current($var);//1
echo next($var);//2  <- Alterou o ponteiro de $var
echo current($var);//2 
$a = $var; // <- Copiou o array
echo current($a); //2 <- Ponteiro na mesma posição de $var.
```

Passagem por referência:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php

Função `current():` http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.current.php

Comment: next() não modifica o array, assim como current() também não; E next() aceita apenas passagem por referência.
Eu gostaria de entender o sentido de o manual ter deixado  explícito a sintaxe `mixed current ( array &$array )`, sendo que ela não funciona assim.

Comment: Não, você pode fazer o teste desta forma:     
`$var = array(1,2,3);
    echo current($var);
    echo next($var);`
Não há nenhuma passagem por referência nisto, e funciona.

Comment: gostaria que você observasse a síntaxe que o Manual colocou lá. É essa que é a questão. Está assim: `array &$array`. Se você olhar no next(), está a mesma coisa.

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.next.php

Comment: A função current() funciona com arrays não referênciados (e até com objetos), e isso é indiscutível (pois funciona, né). A declaração da função (no manual) é que induz a pensar que deve ser um elemento passado por referência. sort(), ksort() e outras funções possuem essa mesma declaração, porém current() foi a única que eu vi que está, digamos, "errada"

Comment: Entendi, é porque nestas funções, como o next(), a posição do ponteiro é modificada, mas não precisa passar por referência, a própria função o faz.

Comment: Vou postar um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Acho que quando eu disse "passar por referência" eu me ao argumento de current ser obrigatoriamente uma variável com um array. Acho que eu posso ter confundido sua resposta, mas, falando em "passagem por referência", eu me refiro a quando você assinala no argumento de uma função com o operador `&`, indicando que ali deverá ser obrigatório uma variável no parâmetro (que será usada por referência). Eu creio que é por isso que se chama "passagem". É diferente da referência pela atribuição de `=&`.

Comment: Sim, isso `$var1 =& func();` é ligação por referência.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15656/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-marcelo-aymone).

Comment: No essencial eu penso bem parecido com você: como `current` não modifica a array (não move o ponteiro), ela não gera o erro. Porém, acho que isso não ocorre porque a função deixa de receber o argumento por referência. Pra mim ela sempre recebe. As outras falham porque o argumento não é uma variável, e não faria sentido avançar o ponteiro nesses casos (veja minha resposta para mais detalhes).

Answer (score 11):

Observando o comportamento descrito por você fica claro que isto deve ser um erro no manual do php. Minha suspeita é de que como o php utiliza a técnica de `Copy-On-Write`, ele apenas gera erro quando o ponteiro (`referencia`) do array for modificado.

No caso da função `current` o php não está mudando o valor do ponteiro, apenas retornando sua posição.

Acredito que seja interessante abrir um bug-report no php e solicitar para que adicionem uma observação ao manual, para deixar mais claro o funcionamento da função.

Comment: Acho que a gambiarra do manual está aqui: _"Todo array tem um ponteiro interno para o elemento"_. Mas os caras deixaram lá `mixed current(array &$array)`. Não existe nenhuma nota que em versões superiores ao php 5.1 ela passa a se comportar de maneira diferente

Comment: vamos acompanhar https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68995

Answer (score 7):

Não acho que o manual esteja errado, apenas incompleto. Não tenho familiaridade suficiente com o [código-fonte do PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src) para poder rastrear o problema até o ponto onde a mensagem de erro é emitida, mas creio ter entendido o que acontece.

O problema não é termos ou não uma referência; como a função é definida com `&$array` como parâmetro, o argumento que ela recebe é sempre uma referência para a array passada. Eu acredito que você está enfatizando a parte errada da mensagem de erro:

> Only variables can be passed by reference

A chave aqui é ***only variables***, e não *passed by reference*. Em `next([1, 2, 3]);`, você não passa uma variável, passa uma array literal. Não existe nenhuma referência a ela fora do escopo da função `next`; assim que ela retornar, a contagem de referências da estrutura que representa a array será `0`, e a memória passa a ser coletável pelo "lixeiro".

Não faz sentido as funções que movem o ponteiro da array quererem alterar o estado de um objeto que deixará de existir assim que elas retornarem. Mover o ponteiro é uma operação dispensável, e elas têm uma guarda contra isso em algum lugar (não sei bem onde, mas se olhar o código-fonte elas diferem em uma ou duas linhas – exemplos: [`next`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L856) e [`current`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L922)). Existem inclusive testes para garantir que esse uso gere um erro ([exemplo](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/128eda843f7dff487fff529a384fee3c5494e0f6/ext/standard/tests/array/array_next_error1.phpt)).

Repare que o erro não ocorre se a array for atribuída a uma variável, e a variável for passada à função:

```
next($var = [1, 2, 3]);
```

Nesse caso, `$var` existe no escopo onde a função foi chamada, ou seja, continua disponível após a chamada e não pode ser reclamada pelo *garbage collector*.

Quando você pega o valor atual com `current`, isso não modifica o estado da array; nesse caso, o PHP não vê problemas e deixa passar. Dentro das minhas limitações de conhecimento quanto aos detalhes de implementação do PHP, essa é a avaliação que consegui fazer. Talvez eu esteja errado, se alguém tiver evidências disso favor me avisar.