# problemas ao apagar arquivo do ficheiro unlink()

Tags: php, html

eu gostaria de apagar um arquivo no ficheiro, e nada está indo bem de o seguinte erro Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference voces poderia me orientar para resolver esse erro? ficarei agradecido!  Link da imagem:

```
<a id="photo-'.$resultfotos['id'].'" href="site.php?userid='.$user_id.'&pageid='.$page.'&fotoid='.$resultfotos['id'].'">
   <img src="uploads/photos/'.$resultfotos['foto'].'"/>
</a>
```

Link para excluir a foto:

Excluir a foto //eu fiz um include na pagina "deletefotos.php"//

```
<?php 
   $image = end(explode('-',$_GET['photo']));
   $result = Pagina::minhaFoto($imagem,$user_id); 
   if($result['res']){
      if(Pagina::delFoto($idDaimagem)){
         if(file_exists('../uploads/photos'.$result['foto'])){
            unlink('../uploads/photos'.$result['foto']);
         }
      }
   } ?>
```

classe da pagina, pagina.class.php

```
<?php
 static function minhaFoto($imagem){
   $select = self::getConn()->prepare('SELECT `pagina` FROM `fotos` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1');
   $select->execute(array($imagem));
   if($select->rowCount()==1){
      $asfoto = $select(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $dados['res'] = self::myEvent($asfoto['pagina'],$user_id);
      $dados['foto'] = $asfoto['foto'];
      return $d; 
  } 
}

static function delFoto($idDaimagem){
   $del = self::getConn()->prepare('DELETE FROM `fotos` WHERE `id`=?');
   return $del->execute(array($idDaimagem));
}     
?>
```

Comment: Se alguma pergunta resolveu o problema marque ela como aceita, veja mais detalhes em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que `end()` espera uma referência ou seja uma variável faça, a atribuição em dois passos.

Mude:

```
$image = end(explode('-',$_GET['photo']));
```

Para:

```
$nome = explode('-',$_GET['photo'])
$ext = end($nome);
```

Fique atento para assinatura de funções com `&` ele significa que o argumento deve ser passado como referência na maioria das vezes.

> mixed end ( array &$array )

**Relacionado:**

[Duvida sobre função PHP 'end'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83801/91)

Answer (score 3):

Correta a resposta do @rray. O problema é em relação ao `end` aceitar apenas variáveis, e não expressões de array. Portanto, essa função aceita um argumento que seja uma variável, por se tratar de um parâmetro com referência.

Existe uma forma de driblar essa limitação da função `end`.

Assim:

```
function last(array $array)
{
    return end($array);
}
```

Dessa forma, o `$array` que é parâmetro de `last`, é passado para `end` como argumento, tornando-se referência para `end`, e podendo ser expressão para `last`.

Exemplo:

```
echo last(explode('-', '1-2-3')); // Imprime '3'
```

Comment: Boa ideia a função, +1

Comment: Eu vi no código-fonte do `laravel 3`. Dá pra enganar as funções que aceitam referência assim. Por exemplo, pra pegar o primeiro item do array: `function first($a) { return reset($a) }`.  Ex: `first([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: :D laravel. Tem outra pergunta sua ... q fala de uma função que segundo o manual so aceita referências, mas por algum motivo pra la de confuso aceita valores.

Comment: Do [current](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/24992/91)