# Pegar a primeira e a última data de uma array

Tags: php, array

Em PHP tenho essa array:

```
$locados = array('2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08');
```

Essas datas dentro da array representam dois alugueis diferentes de um apartamento:

Aluguel 1: 2016-01-01 até 2016-01-03

Aluguel 2: 2016-01-06 até 2016-01-08

Minha dúvida, como eu consigo isso com PHP, detectar um grupo de datas e falar qual é a primeira e qual a última.

Comment: Respondi mas, relendo novamente parece que está tentando na verdade dividir no meio e fazer 2 grupos? Tem mais detalhes do que exatamente precisa?

Comment: Você retorna assim do seu banco de dados ? não é algo como Pessoa X alugou lugar Y do dia x a dia y ?  Poste o seu sql ou como um exemplo da tabela que você pega estas informações

Comment: A tabela de reserva até tem a data de chekin e checkout, o problema é que o cliente administra mal as reservas, não muda o status dela, está sempre como uma nova reserva e não como uma reserva paga ou confirmada, então tenho que usar as datas de cada apartamento para fazer esse controle de períodos de aluguel... infelizmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicação no próprio comentário do código

```
$locados = array('2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08'); // Array a ser tratada

$dif = "86400"; // 1 dia em segundos (coeficiente)
$count = 0; // Inicializa contador de quantos intervalos haverá

for($i = 0; $i < count($locados); $i++) { // Laço FOR até quado existir índice na array a ser tratada
    // Função 'strtotime' converte em segundos uma data
    if((strtotime($locados[$i+1]) - strtotime($locados[$i])) == $dif) { // Calcula se uma data e a data seguinte possui interval de 1 dia (86400 segundos) 
        $resultado[$count][] = $locados[$i]; // Sendo verdadeira a condição de cima inicia nova array incluindo data
    } else {
        $resultado[$count][] = $locados[$i]; // Sendo falsa, inclui a última data do intervalo atual
        $count++; // Incrementa $count (+1) para próximo índice (intervalo) ser criado no laço
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($resultado); // Print na Array $resultado
```

> Principal função utilizada `strtotime` -> Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Não era isso, eu preciso trabalhar com as datas. Saber os períodos de datas dentro dessa array.

2016-01-01 até 2016-01-03 |  2016-01-06 até 2016-01-08

Repare que não tem data no dia 04 e 05, então o PHP teria que saber esses períodos, entende?

Comment: Ok, vou corrigir a resposta, entendi errado.

Comment: pega o primeiro e último elemento do array, ou somente o valor baseado na data? `$primeiro = $valor[0]; $ultimo = $valor[(count($valor)-1)];`

Comment: Caio, realmente ficou dúvidas. Em relação ao Aluguel 1 e Aluguel 2, como distinguir os valores relacionados ao Aluguel 1 e ao Aluguel 2? Se for isso que estou pensando, uma array bidimensional resolveria 50% do seu problema. Outra coisa é, detectar um grupo de datas e falar qual é a primeira e qual a última, seria data mais antiga e mais recente?

Comment: Oi, isso, seria uma grupo de datas que não tenham espaços entre elas, ele teria que ver quando que tem uma data e até quando ela continua sem ter um intervalo de datas entre ela, entende? ai se tiver um intervalo, no caso do exemplo dia 04 e dia 05 o sistema já reconhece q se formou um primeiro intervalo.

Comment: @caiocafardo editei minha resposta, acredito que isso te atenda, ou ao menos seja o start para aperfeiçoar da maneira que precisar.

Comment: É isso! Valeu meu chapa!

Answer (score 0):

Se a questão é ordenação da lista de dados, eu utilizaria a função `usort`.

Ela ordena um `array` de acordo com uma comparação feita por um `callback`.

Então veja que beleza (uma data foi modificada para verificar que a ordenação funciona):

```
$locados = array(
   '2016-02-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-06', 
   '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08'
);


usort($locados, function ($a, $b)
{
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
});


pr($locados);
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-01-02
    [1] => 2016-01-03
    [2] => 2016-01-06
    [3] => 2016-01-07
    [4] => 2016-01-08
    [5] => 2016-02-01
)
```

Para pegar o último e a primeira data, podemos fazer assim:

```
function first($arr)
{
     return reset($arr);
}


function last($arr)
{
     return end($arr);
}


first($locados); // 2016-01-02

last($locados); // 2016-02-01
```

Se não entendeu o porque de criar novas funções para pegar o último e o primeiro elemento, sugiro que leia essa resposta:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89003/4995

Answer (score 0):

Simples e limpo:

```
<?php

    $array = array('2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08');

    foreach ($array as $element) 
    {
        if ($element === reset($array))
            $minimo = $element;

        if ($element === end($array))
            $maximo = $element;
    }
?>

    Aluguel 1: <?=$minimo?> até <?=$maximo ?>
```