# Qual é a finalidade de array_map aceitar infinitos parâmetros do tipo array, depois do callback?

Tags: php, array

Eu costumo utilizar a função `array_map` para poder fazer algo semelhante ao "list comprehension" do `python`

Algo como:

```
$meses = function($mes)
{
  return sprintf('02%s/%s', $mes, date('Y'));
}

$arrayFormatado = array_map($meses, range(1, 12));

// Retorna: array(){ '01/2015', '02/2015', ...}
```

Porém agora, olhando bem o Manual, percebi que depois do primeiro parâmetro o número de `arrays` passados podem ser infinitos:

```
array array_map ( callback $callback , array $arr1 [, array $... ] )
```

Qual é a finalidade disso?

Comment: Para que servem as _arrays_ ?

Comment: Ainda me estou a perguntar - _"O que queres tu saber ao certo"_ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter

Comment: Acho que ao mostrar a diferença de uso tradicional e questionar por que é que essa função aceita N parâmetros de arrays já deixei claro o suficiente.

Comment: Não que queira parecer arrogante, ou ignorante, mas na própria página do _PHP.net_, os exemplos são mais que explícitos, e explicam a função e os infinitos argumentos que ela pode receber. E para além disso, a tua pergunta, é também a resposta que procuras, ao meu ver claro ! Talvez eu esteja mesmo a entender mal, mas é essa a razão pela qual mostrei apenas aquele diferença. Dá uma olhada no parágrado antes do exemplo #4 : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php , talvez isto ajude com a dúvida. E por favor não me compreendas mal, tenho as melhores intenções.

Comment: @Edilson, pois é, manual em inglês. Me parece que (quase sempre) o Manual em português vem faltam alguma coisa. E o Manual nem sempre serve para ensinar alguma coisa que preste na prática, ou nem mesmo dizer ao certo [Como funciona uma função](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/24992/como-funciona-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-current). Por isso prefiro perguntar aqui :p

Comment: Ah, como pude eu me esquecer disso *-*, quase nunca leio o manual em português, agora com certeza fui ignorante, não avaliei antes as condições. Contudo acho que a resposta do @Ivan Ferrer te vai ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do `array_map()`, o callback do método pode efetuar um mapeamento com os demais itens da lista.

```
<?php

   $array1 = array('vendedores', 'estudante',     'colaborador');
   $array2 = array('balconista', 'estagiário',    'operário');
   $array3 = array('entregador', 'bibliotecário', 'programador');

   $array_group = array('lista1', 'lista2', 'lista3');

   function mapDadosToCategory($grupos, $array1, $array2, $array3) {

        return array($grupos => array($array1, $array2, $array3));
   }


   $map = array_map('mapDadosToCategory', $array_group, $array1, $array2, $array3); //n arrays mapeados

   echo '<pre>';
    print_r($map);
```

A saída seria isso:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lista1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vendedores
                    [1] => balconista
                    [2] => entregador
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lista2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => estudante
                    [1] => estagiário
                    [2] => bibliotecário
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lista3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => colaborador
                    [1] => operário
                    [2] => programador
                )

        )

)
```

Veja este exemplo:
**http://www.viper-7.com/H9Lx6f**

Comment: +1 Correto, Ivan Ferrer. Seria bom adicionar exemplos à resposta, por conta dos links um dia serem quebrados

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso deva-se ao motivo de que quando você cria cria a função de call back você pode utilizar parâmetros infinitos logo o array_map permite quantos parâmetros for, desde que seja compatível com a sua função de callback.

Answer (score 0):

A finalidade é mapear todos os `arrays` passados ao mesmo tempo. Isso pode ser útil quando for necessário aplicar uma "fusão" em determinados arrays, de maneira que você poderia controlar melhor a saída.

Um pequeno exemplo, onde temos três `arrays`, que serão fundidos, ao gosto do programador :)

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'tree');

$b = array('uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'um passito pra frente maria');

$c = array('um', 'dois', 'três', 'nove');


$all = array_map(function ($a, $b, $c)
{
    return ['a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c];

}, $a, $b, $c);


var_export($all);
```

O  retorno incrívelmente será:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'a' => 'one',
    'b' => 'uno',
    'c' => 'um',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'a' => 'two',
    'b' => 'dos',
    'c' => 'dois',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'a' => 'tree',
    'b' => 'tres',
    'c' => 'três',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'a' => NULL,
    'b' => 'um passito pra frente maria',
    'c' => 'nove',
  ),
)
```