# Como guardar o valor dos índices desse JSON em variável?

Tags: php, json, array, moodle

Eu tenho uma função no php que me retorna isso.

```
[{"id":81,"username":"usuarioteste23"}]
```

Como consigo salvar em uma variável esse ID e em outra variável esse Username?

Obrigado.

Comment: Isso tudo é uma string (json), não é?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Solução

Faça assim:

```
$dados = json_decode('[{"id":81,"username":"usuarioteste23"}]', true);

$id = $dados[0]['id'];

$username = $dados[0]['username'];
```

## Explicação

O que sua função retorna é uma string php, contendo dados serializados em formato `JSON`.

O JSON é utilizado para você fazer intercâmbio de dados computacionais. Ele utiliza a notação de objetos do javascript (não é necessário javascript para lê-lo). Você pode lê-lo com facilidade em várias liguagens, como `PHP`, `java` ou `python`.

No PHP, a função que decodifica dados serializados em `JSON` é `json_decode`. Ela vai transformar um conjunto de dados de `JSON` para PHP (`array`, `object`, `int`, etc...).

No exemplo, eu etilizei `$dados[0]` porque seu `json` possui um objeto dentro de um array. Então, precisamos pegar o índice `0` para capturar o primeiro (e único) valor desse array, que por sua vez contém um objeto com as propriedades id e username.

Para ficar mais fácil de entender (tendo em vista que você sabe que o JSON é um tipo de notação semelhante aos tipos do javascript).

O `array` no json é repesentado por `[]`.

O `objeto` no json é representado por `{}`

O returno de json_decode resultaria na seguinte declaração, se fosse feita em php.

```
$dados = array();

// Object converte para stdClass

$dados[0] = (object)array('id' => 81, 'username' => 'usuarioteste23');
```

Como pode perceber, usei um segundo argumento passado para o `json_decode`, que é o valor `true, que serve para definir se vamos decodificar o json para`array`ou`stdClass`. Nesse caso trabalhei usando um`array`.

O retorno desse `json_decode` com o segundo argumento sendo `true`, seria algo parecido com essa declaração:

```
 $dados = array();

// Sem conversão para stdClass, usei um array simples

$dados[0] = array('id' => 81, 'username' => 'usuarioteste23');
```

Answer (score 0):

Embora a resposta tenha já sido dada - e escolhida - eu acho válido postar outra solução que é bem elegante e que a linguagem traz nativamente (parece até ter sido construído para o seu caso):

```
$json = '[{"id":81,"username":"usuarioteste23"}]';
# agora você tem $id e $username
extract(array_pop(json_decode($json, true)));
```

**Informações adicionais:**

O código acima não é incorreto (como dito por alguém no comentário abaixo), mas ele gerará um WARNING (não erro) se **Strict Standards** está habilitado:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference
```

Isso ocorre pois, por padrão, PHP tenta passar o argumento de array_pop|array_shift por referência e, neste caso, **deveria** ser uma varíavel, não um array construct.

> **Nota:**
>   Não há qualquer relação com má prática ou má ideia -  ao menos nesse
>   caso - em usar a função built-in `extract()`, visto que o que se quer
>   obter é uma variável `$id` e outra chamada `$username`. Se você
>   estiver receoso quanto a colisão de nomes de variáveis, você mesmo até
>   passar um **prefixo** para o terceiro parâmetro de extract().   O uso
>   de extract() é popularmente usado em frameworks (como Laravel) e
>   template engines.

Tendo dito isso, o código deveria ser melhor escrito dessa forma:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('[{"id":81,"username":"usuarioteste23"}]', true);

extract(array_pop($data));
```

Comment: -1 Não estou comentando quando dou negativo, mas dessa vez vou abrir exceção. Array_pop só aceita variáveis (pois o argumento espera uma referência). Esse código geraria um erro. Além do que `extract` é uma péssima ideia, se o json retornar outros nomes que poderiam se transformar em variáveis inexperadas.

Comment: Considerarei tirar o negativo se você melhorar sua resposta. Por exemplo, pode-se adicionar o exemplo que no php5.4 você poderia fazer isso : `json_decode($json, true)[0]`.

Comment: Não entendi pq tantos votos negativos, o warning é fácil de corrigir. +1

Comment: Os votos negativos me pareceram justos sim, mas eu discordo mais é de ficar comentando eles dentro da resposta. A resposta deve ser e unicamente sobre o problema da dúvida. Apenas deve corrigir o problema do código e usar o campo de comentários ou META. Participe do META, leia o que já foi debatido lá, aprenda como funciona a comunidade. Não interprete mal os downvotes eles não são arbitrários (apesar de existir vezes que tem pessoas que o usam de maneira errada). Vou editar a resposta é deixar apenas o que é interessante. Se sentir que precisa discutir isto vá para o META.

Comment: Agora sobre a sua ultima edição, ninguem disse que `extract` é o problema em absoluto, talvez não tenha sido claro, mas o problema é sobrescrever variáveis existentes, talvez um closure resolvesse, faltou a explicação do porque usar `array_pop`. Você se prendeu em justificar o que é certo e errado, mas não explicou o código em si. Explique o que `array_pop` vai fazer de diferença, eu não sei quem deu os downvotes, mas é bem provavel que retirem ;) - fico aguardando.

Comment: Simplesmente use `current` no lugar de `array_pop` e eu tiro o negativo. E @rray,  talvez dependa da versão do php. Esse Warning não é lançado lá a toa, e talvez em alguma versão pode "evoluir" para um outro erro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não disse para deixar o código em uma linha e deixar o warning de boa, se tem algum deve ser tratado. Tem muita coisa no php que não tem razão ou não é coerente vide => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/24992/91 , acho engraçado isso, a documentação diz que algumas funções é obrigatório passar uma referência mas para algumas só gera o warning e funciona .... meio bizarro. Não estou falando para não tratar o warning :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sobre o "evoluir" que você falou, é interessante notar que alguns usam parenteses nessas funções(acho que a mais comum é o `explode()`) para não gerar o warning, porém no php7 mesmo com esses parenteses adicionais ocorre o warning, [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.parentheses)