# como montar o json dessa respectiva chamada

Tags: php, json, libcurl

estou com um problema nao sei como montar o json dessa chamada em php para envio por curl alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
"auto_recurring": {
        "frequency": 1,
        "frequency_type": "months",
        "transaction_amount": 200
 }
```

Comment: Isso já parece ser parte de um formato JSON válido, Qual o problema?

Comment: quero jogar isso no array em php para montar uma requisição para ser enviado ao mercado pago pelo curl. estava pesquisando e para enviar json por curl no php e preciso transformar esse json em array, mas nao tenho ideia como faco isso

Comment: Então é duplicata dessa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109460/como-guardar-o-valor-dos-%c3%adndices-desse-json-em-vari%c3%a1vel (tem várias outras no site fazendo isto, vale a pena uma pesquisada)

Comment: @jandao você precisa fornecer mais informação, para que alguém possa realmente entender oque você pretende fazer, e tentar ti ajudar em algo, de acordo com oque você falou na postagem e com oque comentou não fica claro qual o problema que precisa resolver

Comment: bom vamus la eu preciso fornecer esses parametros para o mercado pago da forma que esta ali. andei pesquisando na internet e a forma que se envia aqueles por `curl` para o mercado pago e em um array, porem como montar esse array? eu pensei em montar assim : `array('auto_recurring' => 'frequency' => 1, 'auto_recurring' => 'frequency_type' => 'months')` assim por diante mas nao sei se e assim que monta para enviar por `curl` para o mercadopago essa e a minha duvida

Comment: j consegui resolver meu problema

Comment: Pode excluir a pergunta ou postar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$array = [
    "auto_recurring" =>[
        "frequency" => 1,
        "frequency_type" => "months",
        "transaction_amount" => 200
    ]
];
```

Depois de se quiser converter para json faça o seguinte:

```
json_encode($array);
```

O output da linha acima é:

```
"auto_recurring": {
        "frequency": 1,
        "frequency_type": "months",
        "transaction_amount": 200
 }
```